# Notepad++ doesn't open my html file but the google home page

Tags: javascript, html, notepad++

I'm trying to learn html and javascript but I'm having problems opening html files with notepad++.

I downloaded notepad++ and I created a simple html file.

```
<html>  
    <body>
        Hello world!
    </body>
</html>
```

I uncommented the option to run a file with chrome in the shortcut.xml file.

[image]

Finally, I added the chrome link in the notepad++ folder.

When I run the file with chrome, the browser opens the google home page instead of the file.

[image]

[image]

Whereas, if I write the code in notepad, and I open the file with chrome, the browser opens it up correctly.

[image]

I've not set a cloud path yet. Do I have to set one? If yes, which one?

[image]

Comment: You don't need a cloud path. Perhaps you could try updating to the latests notepad++ version? Also, could you please try the following test: Run command (F5) ==> Then write `firefox "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"` and click `RUN` (instead of storing command). Does it work like that?

Answer (score 0):

The menu item *should* say "Launch in Firefox" - corresponding to the `name=` attribute in the settings file, the fact it isn't means that your likely editing the wrong settings file.

If you have set *Settings -> Preferences -> Cloud* to a directory then that's where the correct XML file will be, otherwise look in both *%APPDATA%\Roaming\Notepad++* & the install dir for other copies of the file.

---

> > what are the best editors for html and javascript

Subjective, but take a look @ https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html

Comment: I've not set a cloud path yet. Please check out the screenshot I just added (the last one). Do I have to set a cloud path?

Answer (score 0):

Place the path into quotation marks

```
<Command name="Edge" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)</Command>
```

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't try to run it from notepad++ itself. Instead, Just Right Click your file from the file explorer and Open with Google Chrome. It should open your file that way.

Comment: I already wrote that I did that and it works, but I'm also trying to make it work with notepad++. By the way, what are the best editors for html and javascript?

Comment: You can use Visual Studio Code, Dreamweaver, Brackets, IntelliJ IDEA. Those are some best editors for HTML and javaScript.

Comment: Did you tried to restart notepad++ after you made that change to the shortcus.xml file?

Comment: Yes, I saved the shortcut.xlm file and I restarted notepad++.

Comment: Can you show the URL that you're getting in Google Chrome when you click launch in chrome? I have the same settings as you have, I can still run any html file from 'Run' option. I'm not sure why it won't for you. Maybe you should try to reinstall the software, and if it still doesn't work, update the version or if you already have the latest version then try installing an older version of notepad++.

Comment: The URL area is empty. By the way, I'll probably use pycharm.